# Carregara Load Control C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, usercontrol

Preciso adicionar um UserControl condicionalmente. De que forma? caso a variável Pap_id seja igual a 134, preciso carregar um UserControl exibe dois inputText para o usuário informar uma data de início e uma data de fim:

```
  var Pap_id = Convert.ToString(Request.Params["app"]);

  if (Pap_id == "134"){

     //Adicionar UserControl      

  }
```

Esse código está no PageLoad() de uma página chamada detalhes.aspx. Gostaria de saber como faço isso, pois se eu arrastar o usercontrol para a página ela aparece para as outras aplicações também, mas como dito, quero que seja mostrado apenas quando a condição for atendida, if(Pap_id == 134).

Comment: Você não quer usar o recurso `Visible="true"` dos componentes?

Comment: Opa, sou iniciante no Asp.Net/C#, no caso com esse recurso deixaria ele como false e passaria para true dentro do if, é isso?

Comment: Simples assim! Seta `true` aparece, seta `false` oculta.. `TextBox.Visible = "true"`

Comment: Certo, vc saberia me dizer como faço para pegar a referência do UserControl que está na página aspx no Codebehind?

Comment: dá uma olhada nesse exemplo: [link](http://raphaelcardoso.com.br/criando-user-controls-em-asp-net/)